# Creating a sticky manipulator that inserts a delimiter between each token of an output stream

Tags: c++, ostream

I've seen examples that allow you to create a manipulator that inserts delimiters but none of those manipulators are sticky. That is, the manipulator returns a special class that inserts the delimiter, rather than modifying the output stream permanently so that it can do it on its own.

I want to be able to do this:

```
std::cout << sep(", ");
std::cout << "hello" << "world";
// "hello, world"
```

At the moment this prints `"h, e, l, l, o, w, o, r, l, d"` when I need it to be `"hello, world"`. The reason I'm getting the wrong output is because I put the printing in the `overflow()` method and `overflow()` is being called for each character. I'm not sure where is the appropriate place to put it.

Sorry about it being verbose. If I knew a simpler way to write it I would. Just start from the bottom and work your way up:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

// index for delimiter
int separator() {
  static int idx = std::ios_base::xalloc();
  return idx;
}

// index for storage of dynamically-allocated buffer
int rdbuffer() {
  static int idx = std::ios_base::xalloc();
  return idx;
}

struct custom_separator : std::streambuf {
 public:
  custom_separator(std::ostream& _stream)
      : stream(_stream), buffer(_stream.rdbuf()) {}

  int_type overflow(int_type c) {
    // has a token been read already
    if (token_read) {
      char* delim = static_cast<char*>(stream.pword(separator()));
      // print delim
      buffer->sputn(delim, strlen(delim));
    }
    token_read = true;
    return buffer->sputc(c);
  }

 private:
  std::ostream& stream;
  std::streambuf* buffer;
  bool token_read = false;
};

// deletes the buffer and the delimiter
void cleanup(std::ios_base::event evt, std::ios_base& str, int idx) {
  if (evt == std::ios_base::erase_event) {
    delete static_cast<const char*>(str.pword(idx));
    delete static_cast<custom_separator*>(str.pword(rdbuffer()));
  }
}

std::ostream& set_separator(std::ostream& os, const char* str) {
  if (!os.bad()) {
    // If a separator string doesn't exist, assign os a buffer that prints one
    if (!os.pword(separator())) {
      auto buf = new custom_separator(os);
      os.rdbuf(buf);
      // this is to keep track of buf so we can delete it later
      os.pword(rdbuffer()) = static_cast<void*>(buf);
      os.register_callback(cleanup, separator());
    }
    // delete the previous separator
    delete static_cast<const char*>(os.pword(separator()));
    // store the new one
    os.pword(separator()) = (void*)(str);
  }
  return os;
}

struct sep {
  explicit sep(const char* _sep) 
    : separator(new char[strlen(_sep) + 1]) {
    strcpy(separator, _sep);
  }
  sep(const sep&) = delete;
  sep(const sep&&) = delete;
  char* separator;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const sep& manip) {
  set_separator(os, manip.separator);
  return os;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << sep(", ");
  std::cout << "hello";
  std::cout << "world";
  // "h, e, l, l, o, w, o, r, l, d"
}
```

The main issue with `overflow()` is that I don't know when to detect when the end of a token like `"hello"` has been read to know when to insert.

Comment: There's no such functionality in the C++ library.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's why I'm making my own.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik do you mean its not possible to write such a thing (like my own kind of std::width or std::left etc)

Comment: maybe you have to write your own stream thats wraps (or is derived from ) ostream

Comment: @pm100 That would defeat the purpose of the manipulator, which is to modify the stream in an easy way instead of having to do it yourself. Plus I don't want to have to create a new stream class if I want to use multiple different output streams in a program.

Comment: Could it be that you are looking for an ostream_joiner? As defined in experimental?

Comment: `std::width` and `std::left` update the stream's `ios_base` and its members. That's all they do. Unless you can discover something in `ios_base` that implements this functionality, there's nothing that can be done here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Additionally, new line break processing (new line symbol) has been added so that the separator is not added during the transfer (after new line).

```
#include <iostream>

class MyStream
{
    public:
        struct Sep
        {
            Sep (const std::string& sep_value = ""):
                m_sep(sep_value)
            {
            }
            
            operator std::string()
            {
                return m_sep;
            }
                
            private:
            std::string m_sep;
        };
        
        MyStream& operator << (const Sep& sep)
        {
            m_sep = sep;
            m_add_sep = false;
            return *this;
        }
        
        MyStream& operator << (const std::string& str)
        {
            if(str.find(MyStream::endl) != std::string::npos)
                m_add_sep = false;
            operator<< <std::string>(str);
            m_add_sep = false;
            return *this;
        }
        
        template <typename T>
        MyStream& operator << (const T& value)
        {
            if(m_add_sep)
                std::cout << static_cast<std::string>(m_sep);
            std::cout << value;
            m_add_sep = true;
            return *this;
        }
        
    static const std::string endl;
        
    private:
        Sep m_sep;
        bool m_add_sep = false;
};

const std::string MyStream::endl = std::string("\n");

int main()
{
    MyStream stream;
    stream << "hello" << "world" << MyStream::endl; // prints "helloworld"
    stream << MyStream::Sep(", ");
    stream << "hello" << "world" << MyStream::endl; // prints "hello, world"
    stream << 1 << 2;
    stream << 3 << MyStream::endl; // both lines prints "1, 2, 3"
    stream << MyStream::Sep();
    stream << 1 << 2 << 3 << MyStream::endl; // prints "123"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Here's a possible solution. The separator is the **same for all streams**.

   ```
    namespace alt_std
    {
      struct sep
      {
        sep(const char* s) { s_ = s; }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const sep& sm)
        {
          return os;
        }

        inline static std::string s_{};
      };

      std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const char* s)
      {
        return std::operator<<(os, s), std::operator<<(os, sep::s_);
      }
    }

    int main()
    {
      using namespace alt_std;

      std::cout << sep(" ") << "hello";
      std::cout << "world" << std::endl; // "hello world\n"

      std::cout << sep("") << "hel" << "lo"; // "hello"
    }
   ```
2. If you want to do it at the stream object level, it's more difficult because stream objects don't have a **custom storage space** where you can store the value of the separator.
3. Or you could simply **wrap** the stream object:

   ```
    template< typename OS >
    struct wrapper
    {
      wrapper(OS& os, const char* sep) : os_{ os }, sep_{ sep } {}

      template< typename T>
      friend wrapper& operator<<(wrapper& os, const T& v)
      {
        os.os_ << v << os.sep_;
        return os;
      }

      OS& os_;
      std::string sep_;
    };

    int main()
    {
      wrapper os{ std::cout, " " };
      os << "hello" << "world";
    }
   ```